# is there an easy way to select the whole top of a texture?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have a model which is UV unwrapped with 1 image texture.

[image]

Now i want to select the whole top of the lady's outfit (which is partly selected and gray).

I know i can use circle select, but because the edges/boundary are creased i hoped for something like...select until crease ...? or something similar? i know you can select faces by material, unfortunately it is just one material. Selecting by color would be helpful in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: `L` not working for you? where you can select by Linked (by normal, material, seam, sharp, etc)

Comment: thats what i was searching for...sorry, i am texture beginner :) you can write an answer for that. I don't know why but i thought L would always connect all...didn't look to that small box on the bottom left ‍♂️

Comment: oh btw chris there is another useful feature which took me some time to discover, not sure if you already know, but can come in pretty handy! clicking a face and then Ctrl clicking a face far further down will select the whole line of faces. saved me alot of time!

Comment: that i knew ;) but now i am struggling with "just painting" that selecting faces...and not over it :( oh man...i am so dumb with texture painting... :(

Comment: yeah texture painting was very tricky and confusing for me at first! my advice that cost me a hard lesson learned, SAVE your image texture when painting! saving blend file will not save your painted image! i lost hours of texture painting work coz i didn't realize i needed to save the image itself! you will see it in the Image menu it has an asterisk * Image* if it is unsaved.

Comment: @Chris If you want to paint just the selected faces, enable the  _Paint Mask_ option next to the _Texture Paint_ mode menu (two overlapping squares symbol). This way you only paint on faces which are selected in _Edit Mode_.

Comment: thank you Gordon. I think i found the button....but i am still too dumb to paint with it because now painting doesn't work at all. I think i have to continue watching beginner texture paint tutorials because i am missing the basics... :(

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: now it worked ;) i am learning slooooooooowly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can press <kbd>L</kbd> while hovering over the area you want to select. There are also *Select Linked* options and it looks like you can use the *Material* option.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

3 useful selection techniques:

Select a portion of the model, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and choose in the black box where to limit the selection.

Select a face, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, select another face away from it. Keep adding to the selection holding thoose two keys.

In your case maybe the fastest way is to Alt click on the boundary loops and go to menu Select > Select loops > Select Loop Inner-Region, or press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide them, press <kbd>L</kbd> to select the shirt, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide (and add to selection).

[image]

Comment: sorry josh but because Harry wrote the comment earlier, i gave him the check. Thanks for your answer anyway. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, absolutely :)

Comment: thank you, i still upvoted josh's besides i can get my sportsmanship badge hahaha :)

Comment: Thx Harry, Josh deserves it - he helped me a few times with his great answers and knowledge‼️